# Pass array with pointer, using if (? operator) statement

Tags: c++

How do i do this?

```
uint_fast8_t array1[100];
uint_fast8_t array2[100];

void get_a(bool which_one)
{
uint_fast8_t *array[] = which_one ? &array2 : &array1; //doesn't work
}
```

This throws a error saying "Can't convert uint_fast8_t(*)[100] to uint_fast8_t *[]"

Comment: Are you allowed to used dynamically allocated array ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it is not the pointer but array of pointers

```
   uint_fast8_t *array = which_one ? array2 : array1;
```

Or

```
  uint_fast8_t *array[] = {which_one ? &array2 : &array1}
```

Comment: That fixes it, but wouldn't using a pointer make it faster? Or am i wrong?

Second way does not work.

Comment: @FreeRenca How would using a pointer be faster than using a pointer?

Comment: Is that second snippet valid? `&array1` has type `uint_fast8_t (*)[100]`.  You can't have one of those in an array of `uint_fast8_t*`.